# How to change my iterative method into a recursive method

Tags: java, recursion

How would I change the below method from iterative to recursive?

```
public int[] pascal(int[] previous) 
{

    //The row is 1 element longer than previous row
    int[] row = new int[previous.length + 1];

    //The first and last numbers in row are always 1
    row[0] = 1;
    row[row.length - 1] = 1;

    //The rest of the row can be calculated based on previous row
    for (int i = 1; i < row.length-1; i++) 
    {
        row[i] = previous[i-1] + previous[i];
    }

    return row;
}
```

Comment: Is the recursion some kind of homework requirement? Seems like iterative is a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1):

The "state" of the calculation must be passed through the parameters. So, you would need more parameters than just the `int[] previous` row.

Usually you want to have 2 methods, a public one with the simpler interface, and a private one, which is the one that actually performs the calculation.

In your example, these two methods would be something like:

```
public int[] pascal(int[] previous) { ... call the next overload ... }
private int[] pascal(... all the state needed ...) { ... recursive call or return the value ... }
```

One of the most straightforward ways would be to pass the new row being calculated and the index of the next position that should be calculated as the parameters in the recursive function. So, you would have:

```
private int[] pascal(int[] previous, int currentIndex, int[] row) { ... }
```

Now, your recursive function usually has 2 (or more) cases. For this, you will have two cases:

- if the "currentIndex" is past the last index you need to calculate, we are done -- just return the row as it is now;
- otherwise, calculate the value for the current index, put it in the row, and make a recursive call that will continue the calculation (by either deciding that it has finished, or by calculating and calling again, again, ...)

Let's code these 2 cases:

```
private int[] pascal(int[] previous, int currentIndex, int[] row) {
  if (currentIndex == previous.length) {
    return row;
  } else {
    // do some part of the calculation
    // and make a recursive call that would continue the calculation:
    return pascal(previous, ????, row);
  }
}
```

Do you see why this is the structure of the recursive function?

Ok, onto the real calculation:

```
private int[] pascal(int[] previous, int currentIndex, int[] row) {
  if (currentIndex == previous.length) {
    return row;
  } else {
    int currentValue = previous[currentIndex - 1] + previous[currentIndex];
    row[currentIndex] = currentValue;
    return pascal(previous, currentIndex, row);
  }
}
```

The calculation is done. Now you just have to make your "simpler" function call your recursive function with the appropriate parameters:

```
public int[] pascal(int[] previous) {
  int rowSize = previous.length + 1;
  int[] row = new int[rowSize];
  row[0] = 1;
  row[rowSize - 1] = 1;
  return pascal(previous, 1, row);
}
```

That's it.

As you can see, the "trick" is to keep the "state" in the parameters. Here, `currentIndex` is just like `int i` in your original `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

As it is programmed now, you have to call the function many times in order to get what you want.

A recursive function would call itself. This way you would only call it once to get what you want.

I suppose that you just want one specific row of the triangle. The only parameter you need to pass to the function is the row number.

Imagine that you already have that function programmed and you can call it for a specific row number N-1. Can you write a function that uses the previous one to compute the row N?

Now just take care of the corner cases: first row and maybe negative row numbers.

That said, using this function to display the triangle row by row would be very inefficient!